# How to compare two listboxes

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, compare, visual-studio-2013

i have two listboxes : Lbl and Lblr.
They both get 8 unique random numbers.

Now i made a method to compare a number i selected with all the numbers in the other listbox and if it isn't there it adds it and if it is already in there it removes it.

```
 public void placer(int Z,ListBox box,ListBox boxxer)
    {
        if (boxxer.Items.Contains(Z))
        { box.Items.RemoveAt(box.SelectedIndex); }
        else
        {
            boxxer.Items.Add(Z);
            box.Items.RemoveAt(box.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
```

Now the second step i want to do is to compare all the numbers from one listbox to all the numbers in the other listbox.
But i cannot think of annyother way than to do it with array's and i do not believe thats the most effective way.

Help needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LINQ` for this:

```
var boxItems = box.Items.OfType<int>();
var boxerItems = boxxer.Items.OfType<int>();

bool control = boxItems.OrderBy(x => x)
               .SequenceEqual(boxerItems.OrderBy(y => y));
```

Assuming that all of your items are numbers then this will return **true** if the both listBox contains same numbers ignoring the number's order.You can remove the `OrderBy` method(s) if you want to care about order.